# How do I overlap an image in front of twitter bootstrap's top navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a banner image on my Twitter Bootstrap page, with the top of the image overlapping and in front of the top navbar.

My html code is shown below.  It works for small screen widths, but for wider screens, the top of the image appears behind the navbar. I am using Bootstrap v2.2.2.

Any ideas how to make this work for all screen sizes?  Much appreciated!

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       ...
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .mypic {margin: -120px 0 -20px 10px;}
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mypic">
            <img src="..." width="300"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the z-index CSS attribute to a high value for your .mypic class?

Comment: You are using a fixed nav bar. Is the image to be fixed as well?

Comment: I tried adding position: relative; z-index: 9;  to .mypic, but it made no difference.  @David Taiaroa - good question... no, I did not mean the picture to be fixed.  You've made me look closer at its current behavior: with a small screen-width, the navbar is not actually fixed.  I've removed the "navbar-fixed-top" class and now it does what I want - thanks!  Except that the navbar is now not quite at the top... how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite picture where you are heading with this, but is this a start?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/xdv9m/

You might need to use media queries to refine the results for small window sizes.

**CSS**

```
.mypic {
margin: -120px 0 -20px 10px; /* play with these to position the image */
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
width:300px;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks David.  Your earlier comment has solved it for me - I simply removed the "navbar-fixed-top" and then added body:{padding-top:0;} and I now have the behavior I want. Thanks!